# How to get PreparedStatement from vert.x SqlConnection?

Tags: java, vert.x

I'm using vert.x for storing some data to a database and I have some problem.
I need to insert data to the database like this: `INSERT INTO table1(id, name) VALUES(?,?);`, but I couldn't user method `connection.updateWithParams` because I had an error (I use Greenplum and this database not returning UpdateResult), but in vert.x ver 3.3.3 `connection.execute(sql);` not `executeWithParam` method.
How can I get PrepareStatement from vert.x?

Comment: After you get a `SQLConnection` from vert.x JDBC client, you can [unwrap](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/sql/SQLConnection.html#unwrap--) it to a `java.sql.Connection`. Then you can create a `PreparedStatement`

Comment: @tsegismont Thanks for the help but it is not suitable for me because I'm using vert.x version 3.3.3 and in that version does not have the method ```unwrap```.

Comment: @Oleg in this case the only way is get a `java.sql.Connection` from `io.vertx.ext.jdbc.impl.JDBCConnectionImpl` using reflection: `Connection conn = (Connection) connection.getClass().getDeclaredField("conn").get(connection);`